# How to grep string like $('!

Tags: grep

Trying to grep such string

**$('!**

On `grep -R "$('\!" *` console returns such message: `bash: !": event not found`

Your help is highly appreciated)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works if you escape every single character but don't put quotation marks around the string:

```
grep -R \$\(\'\!f *
```